# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in TicketsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i get a AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in TicketsController#update.
If i select a particular user, the update is not happening.

```
def update

    @selected_group = Group.find_by_id(params[:Department]) unless params[:Department].nil?
    @selected_company = Company.find_by_id(params[:Company]) unless params[:Company].nil?
    @ticketnote_content = params[:Ticketnote] 

    if ((@selected_group != nil) && (@selected_company != nil))

      map_group_to_department
      map_user_to_staff
      update_ticket

      if (@response['response'] == "Failed")
        flash[:error] = response['err_desc']
        redirect_to "/ticket/#{params[:id]}/edit"
        return
      elsif (@response['response'] == "Success")
          @ticketnote_content
          if @ticketnote_content != ""
              add_note_to_ticket
         end
        map_assets_findings_tickets
        flash[:notice] = "Succesfully updated the ticket"
        TicketHistory.create_ticket_history(@assigned_user,@selected_asset,@ticket_params,current_user,@updated_ticket_response,"Updated")
      end
    else

      flash[:error] = "Company or department can't be blank."
      redirect_to "/ticket/#{params[:id]}/edit"
      return
    end
    redirect_to :controller => 'tickets' , :action => 'show', :id => params[:id],:test_id => @test,:ticket_id=> params[:ticket_id]
end
```

Comment: How about a stack trace?

Comment: Why don't you move the last `redirect_to` to after the line with `TicketHistory.create_ticket_history` so you can remove all those `return`s? That would make the conditional logic far clearer.

Comment: FYI: ` if ((@selected_group != nil) && (@selected_company != nil))` should be written as `if @selected_group && selected_company`. Much neater.

Comment: Between `if ((@selected_group != nil) && (@selected_company != nil)) else end` statement redirect_to is already called and after execution of if else statement `redirect_to :controller => 'tickets' , :action => 'show', :id => params[:id],:test_id => @test,:ticket_id=> params[:ticket_id]
` is also called.

Remove your last redirect or use render if you want that part for view.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already used redirect_to within your if else statement and after execution of if else you are redirecting again, which lead this error(you can use only once within each action). In order to resolve this, I would suggest following solutions(the question was not clear, so I may not be right):

**Solution 1**: If your last redirect_to is not required then delete it, i.e.

```
redirect_to :controller => 'tickets' , :action => 'show', :id => params[:id],:test_id => @test,:ticket_id=> params[:ticket_id]
```

**Solution 2**: Update with `and return` in every redirect_to and moving you last redirect_to in your successful response condition(I'm not sure where you want your `Ticket#show`) , i.e.

```
def update
  @selected_group = Group.find_by_id(params[:Department]) unless params[:Department].nil?
  @selected_company = Company.find_by_id(params[:Company]) unless params[:Company].nil?
  @ticketnote_content = params[:Ticketnote] 

  if @selected_group && @selected_company
    map_group_to_department
    map_user_to_staff
    update_ticket

    if (@response['response'] == "Failed")
      flash[:error] = response['err_desc']
      redirect_to "/ticket/#{params[:id]}/edit"
    elsif (@response['response'] == "Success")
      add_note_to_ticket if @ticketnote_content != ""
      map_assets_findings_tickets
      flash[:notice] = "Succesfully updated the ticket"
      TicketHistory.create_ticket_history(@assigned_user,@selected_asset,@ticket_params,current_user,@updated_ticket_response,"Updated")
      redirect_to :controller => 'tickets' , :action => 'show', :id => params[:id],:test_id => @test,:ticket_id=> params[:ticket_id]
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = "Company or department can't be blank."
    redirect_to "/ticket/#{params[:id]}/edit" and return
  end 
end
```

**P.S.**: You can use redirect_to and flash[:message] in one line:

```
redirect_to your_path(params), :notice => "your message"
```